# Horizontal fading with ViewPager is only on the right side

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi there I've got a ViewPager for wich I want to enable HorizontalFadingEdge,
everything works find except that it works only for the left side of the Pager. 
Is there a way to get the desired effect for both left and right ?

Here are some relevant snippets:

XML:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/view_pager_preview"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="96dp">
```

Setup:

```
 pager_preview.setClipToPadding(false);
 pager_preview.setPageMargin(-50);
 pager_preview.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
 pager_preview.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
```

Any ideas about that ?

***Edit:**

I found something like an answer to my question here:
[fading edges working only on top and left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714895/fading-edges-working-only-on-top-and-left)

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                if(position <= -1.0F || position >= 1.0F) {
                    view.setAlpha(0.0F);
                } else if( position == 0.0F ) {
                    view.setAlpha(1.0F);
                } else {
                    // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
                    view.setAlpha(1.0F - Math.abs(position));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Funny but when I add your code the fragments fade from behind. I mean they are all layered with specified alpha and just get to the front when swiping. Maybe explain what this snippet is doing.

Comment: it simply set a alpha with value when page is slide.

Comment: Okay any idea why this code changes the position of the fragments ?